# Trying to send multiple emails without using a for-loop

Tags: asp.net, email, sendgrid, sendmail

[image: screenshot of code]

I wrote this code in ASP.NET to send multiple emails without using a for-loop. In the package manager console, when I execute `dotnet run`, it says my email queued successfully.

However, when I go to the SendGrid API to check my email status it says me emails are being dropped because there is a typo in the email. In terms of the actual emails there is no typo, so I am guessing that it has something to do with the semi-colon that I am adding between each email.

The reason that I am adding the semi-colon is because I saw another post mentioning that is how the individual was able to send multiple emails without using a loop. Any advice on how to fix this issue/send the same email to multiple people without using a for-loop.

I tried switching the colons with commas, but that didn't work either. The email is only working when I have one email.

Comment: You should never ever post a screenshot of your code. It is plain text that you can copy'paste here

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source for the sendgrid client here: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/main/src/SendGrid/Helpers/Mail/SendGridMessage.cs

You can call "AddTos" instead of "AddTo". AddTos accepts a list of email addresses. While AddTo is putting your combined list into single email address which is why it is failing.

Your solution would look something like this:

First convert your list of strings into a list of sendgrid email addresses

```
string[] list_of_emails = new string[4] { "email1@mail.com", "email2@mail.com", "email3@mail.com", "email4@mail.com" };

var mails = list_of_emails.ToList().Select(x => new EmailAddress(x));
```

Then pass that list into your message using AddTos instead of AddTo.

```
msg.AddTos(emails)
```

Check the following for an example using the System.Net.Mail.MailAddress: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vwFit2

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'SelectMany' and no accessible extension method 'SelectMany' accepting a first argument of type 'List<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I am getting this error, any thoughts? I had to switch Select to SelectMany btw due to select not accepting a list.

Comment: I've adjusted the code slightly and added an dotnetfiddle example.